# warning:0 flag ignored with precision and '%x' gnu_printf format

Tags: c, data-structures, warnings, printf

i am getting the following warning when i compile in C.

```
   ../tcpuip/uip_arp.c: In function 'display_arp_table':
    ../tcpuip/uip_arp.c:547: warning: '0' flag ignored with precision and '%x' gnu_p
    rintf format
    ../tcpuip/uip_arp.c:547: warning: '0' flag ignored with precision and '%x' gnu_p
    rintf format
    ../tcpuip/uip_arp.c:547: warning: '0' flag ignored with precision and '%x' gnu_p
    rintf format
    ../tcpuip/uip_arp.c:547: warning: '0' flag ignored with precision and '%x' gnu_p
    rintf format
    ../tcpuip/uip_arp.c:547: warning: '0' flag ignored with precision and '%x' gnu_p
    rintf format
    ../tcpuip/uip_arp.c:547: warning: '0' flag ignored with precision and '%x' gnu_p
    rintf format
    ../tcpuip/uip_arp.c:547: warning: '0' flag ignored with precision and '%x' gnu_p
    rintf format
    ../tcpuip/uip_arp.c:547: warning: '0' flag ignored with precision and '%x' gnu_p
    rintf format
    ../tcpuip/uip_arp.c:547: warning: '0' flag ignored with precision and '%x' gnu_p
    rintf format
    ../tcpuip/uip_arp.c:547: warning: '0' flag ignored with precision and '%x' gnu_p
    rintf format
    ../tcpuip/uip_arp.c:547: warning: '0' flag ignored with precision and '%x' gnu_p
    rintf format
    ../tcpuip/uip_arp.c:547: warning: '0' flag ignored with precision and '%x' gnu_printf format
```

the line where the error comes is

```
        RELEASE_MSG("MAC: %0.2x.%0.2x.%0.2x.%0.2x.%0.2x.%0.2x  ",(unsigned char)tabptr->ethaddr.addr[0],(unsigned char)tabptr->ethaddr.addr[1],(unsigned char)tabptr->ethaddr.addr[2],(unsigned char)tabptr->ethaddr.addr[3],(unsigned char)tabptr->ethaddr.addr[4],(unsigned char)tabptr->ethaddr.addr[5]);
```

tabptr is a pointer of struct arp_entry

```
PACKED struct arp_entry {
  u16_t ipaddr[2];
  struct uip_eth_addr ethaddr;
  u8_t time;
#ifdef _ALIGNED_
  u8_t dummy;
#endif
}
```

and ethadder is a pointer for struct uip_eth_addr

```
PACKED struct uip_eth_addr {
  u8_t addr[6];
}  ;
```

Please if anyone can share some light on this warning. I just know that %0.2x means character as two digit HEX. Help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The format string `%0.2x` means:

- print an unsigned integer in hex
- print at least two numbers
- pad it from left with zeros

Since the precision defines the minimum number of digits to output, the zero padding will be ignored (from the specification). You can use `%.2x` or `%02x` that will do what you want.

To get

```
   1
  11
55555
```

You'd use `%4x`.

```
  01
  11
 111
```

would be `%4.2x`

```
0001
0011
55555
```

would be `%04x` or `%.4x`.

Note that there is difference when the value is signed. The precision defines the number of *digits*, meaning the value will occupy one more space for the sign. With minimum output width, sign is already counted:

```
$ printf "%.5i\n%05i\n" '-11' -11
-00011
-0011
```

Answer (score 3):

You certainly wanted to write:

`%02x` instead of `%0.2x`

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `%2.2x` would be 2-digit hex.  `0` is a format flag indicating zero padding instead of blank padding, but since you didn't specify a field width, only a precision, it is meaningless.